# Deleting a JLabel from a JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon, jlayeredpane

I have a layered pane which holds an animation of sorts. I am using a Jlabel (breakB) to display a breaking animation over a block which is breaking. The problem comes up when the block breaks. The label should dissapear, but instead it stays visible. I have been looking for solutions for hours and really have no idea whats going on so any help would be much appreciated.

```
class breakBlock implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        damageCount+=1;
        System.out.println(damageCount);
        JLabel breakB = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon breakIcon = new ImageIcon();


        if(digDown){
            blockInt = standingOn;
        } else {blockInt = nextTo;}


        if(damageCount == 1){
            breakIcon =  new ImageIcon(break01);

        }

        if(damageCount == 2){
            breakIcon =  new ImageIcon(break02);
        }

        if(damageCount == 3){
            breakIcon =  new ImageIcon(break03);

        }

        if(damageCount == 4){ 
            breakIcon =  new ImageIcon(break04);
        }

        if(damageCount == 5){
            breakIcon =  new ImageIcon(break05);
        }


        breakB.setIcon(breakIcon);
        breakB.setBounds(solidObjects.get(blockInt).getX(), solidObjects.get(blockInt).getY(), breakIcon.getIconHeight(), breakIcon.getIconWidth());
        layeredPane.add(breakB, new Integer(2), 0);

        if(damageCount == 6){
            layeredPane.remove(solidObjects.get(blockInt));
            layeredPane.remove(breakB);
            layeredPane.repaint(); // sometimes needed
            solidObjects.remove(blockInt);
            damageCount = 0;
            breakBlock.stop();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are not removing the proper instance of your `JLabel`. As far as I can see, you are not keeping a reference of the `breakB` you are adding to your `JLayeredPane` and thus, unless you rely on some crappy algorithm to find it back, you are removing something which is actually not in your `JLayeredPane`.

Comment: You have'nt provided the `global access` to each `JLabel` `breakB` added to `layeredPane` . And the `JLabel` that you are removing from `layeredPane` in fact does'nt exist on `layeredPane` , It is just a `local` `variable` created within `actionPerformed` . So as a matter of fact the desired `JLabel` is not removed from `layeredPane` when the condition `damageCount == 6` becomes `true`.

Comment: So should I make breakB a global variable or what?

EDIT: Ok so I made breakB a global variable and it is working now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is the fact that you're creating a local label in the `actionPerformed` method...

```
JLabel breakB = new JLabel();
```

This means, that each time you come into the method, you are creating a new instance of the label, meaning you no longer have a reference to any of the existing labels when you come to remove it.

Consider creating a single instance of the `breakB` variable or maintain some kind of list so you know which ones need to be removed, if you need more then one...